# xcode split NSString to other NSStrings

Tags: xcode, nsstring, split

```
{"Title":"Chatroom","Year":"2010","Rated":"R","Released":"11 Aug 2010","Genre":"Drama, Thriller","Director":"Hideo Nakata","Writer":"Enda Walsh, Enda Walsh","Actors":"Aaron Johnson, Imogen Poots, Matthew Beard, Hannah Murray","Plot":"A group of teenagers encourage each other's bad behavior.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0MjM5MDM2MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzg1MzY0Mw@@._V1._SX320.jpg","Runtime":"1 hr 37 mins","Rating":"5.3","Votes":"1000","ID":"tt1319704","Response":"True"}
```

i get this data with nsstring and my question is how to split data that , separates to another nsstrings, but i want to make as commas so much nsstrings

Comment: Looking at that data I think you'd be better off looking for a JSON parser, which should give you an NSDictionary or similar for traversing the data structure.

Comment: the data are correct, i just want to split text between , everyone to an nsstring, not all of them to an other nsstring , maybe to an array but multiline array so i can use everything separate

Answer (score 14):

Use the following

```
NSString *str; //Pass your string to str
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
  // Here just take strings one by one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *string= //pass the string whatever you want.
    NSArray *splitArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; //it separates the string and store it in the different different indexes.

Ex:
    NSString *str= @"one,two,three";
    NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; //it separates the string and store it in the different different indexes(one is at index 0 ,two is at index 1 and three is at index 2).
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and how can i use index of array? how can i copy index[1] to nsstring and etc?

Comment: NSString *secondString = [array objectAtIndex:1];